# What is the way to add horizontal scroll on material-ui table with many columns?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I follow [this table example](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table) for react material-ui framework and I am looking for a possibility to make my table scrollable horizontally when I have a lot of columns.

For instance I have many columns that are squeezed to fit page width, hence their content is shortened.

I think it's described in material-ui spec by link [Display the full column content and enable horizontal scrolling in the table container](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-interaction).

So I wonder if it's possible in material-ui.

Answer (score 2):

Only overflow-x is not enough. Adding 'flex-basis' and 'flex-shrink' properties to the columns is also required. In below example, adding flex-basis of 35% to 3 columns grows the table width to 105% and 'flex-shrink: 0' ensures that the columns will not be shrinked when the width is not enough:

[image]

app.component.html

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="payments" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8 overflow-x-auto">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="payment_hash">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Payment Hash</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">{{payment?.payment_hash}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="path">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Path</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">{{payment?.path}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="payment_preimage">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Payment Pre Image</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">{{payment?.payment_preimage}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

app.component.css

```
.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
    /* 
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 35%;
    */
    flex: 0 0 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `min-width` property to your table cells along with `overflow-x` for the table container. This will prevent the columns from shrinking. You don't have to make the table container into a flexbox here and you can take advantage of features like fixed-header as well.

Answer (score -1):

I am just starting with React, and not familiar with the material-ui table.

But, HTML tables can be made to allow scrolling horizontally with css.
You can do:

```css
.YourTableClassName {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just simply use

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

this is a trick that just communicate with HTML not with react