# Floating Scroll Bar in mat-table angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, mat-table

I am struggling to add a floating scroll bar to my mat-table. Because i have to go all the way bottom  to scroll to left and right. 
I have found an example in Jquery.
Is there anyway to add this to Angular material table. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/45rEs/show/

[image]

This is my mat-table code:

```
<div class="panel__content no-padding fleet-overview-table">
    <div *ngIf="equipmentDataLoading || _loading != 0" [class.loading-initial]="equipmentDataLoading"
        [class.loading-next-page]="_loading != 0">
        <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>   
    <mat-table *ngIf="!equipmentDataLoading && _loading == 0" class="table-material table-material-scroll table-material--striped table-material--hover table-material--full-width"
        #componentTable [dataSource]="componentViewDataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortChanged($event)"
        [@fadeInOut] [matSortActive]="_currentSort.active" matSortDisableClear [matSortDirection]="_currentSort.direction">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Serial">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Serial')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <div class="SerialAndUnitText">{{row.Equipment.Serial}}</div>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Unit">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Unit')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <div class="SerialAndUnitText">{{row.Equipment.Unit}}</div>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Model">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Model')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Equipment.MakeModelFamily.Model.Title}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Site">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Site')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="cell--jobsite">
                <div class="SerialAndUnitText"> {{row.Equipment.JobSite.Title}} </div>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="CurrentSMU">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Current SMU')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="text-center"> {{row.Equipment.SMU}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="LastInspectionDate">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Last Inspection
                Date')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="cell--date"> {{row.LastInspection.Date | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="LastInspectionSMU">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Last Inspection
                SMU')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="text-center"> {{row.LastInspection.SMU}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="NextInspectionSMU">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Next Inspection
                Date/SMU')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="text-center">
                <span *ngIf="row.Equipment.NextInspectionDate == '1900-01-01T00:00:00'">-</span>
                <span *ngIf="row.Equipment.NextInspectionDate != '1900-01-01T00:00:00'" class="component-span top {{getNextInspectionCSSClass(row.Equipment.NextInspectionDate)}}">{{(row.Equipment.NextInspectionDate
                    | date : 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}}/{{row.Equipment.NextInspectionSMU}}</span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="sides">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(0,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{Translate('Left')}}
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(0,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{Translate('Right')}}
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Link">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Link')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(1,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(1,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(1,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(1,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="HoursOnLink">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Hours on Link')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(2,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(2,1, row.Components)}} {{Translate('hrs')}}
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(2,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(2,2, row.Components)}} {{Translate('hrs')}}
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Bush">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Bush')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(3,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(3,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(3,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(3,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="BushTurned">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Bush Turned')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(4,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(4,1, row.Components)}}
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(4,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(4,2, row.Components)}}
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Shoe">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Shoe')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(5,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(5,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(5,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(5,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="FrontIdler">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Front Idler')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(6,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(6,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(6,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(6,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="RearIdler">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Rear Idler')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(7,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(7,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(7,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(7,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Sprocket">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Sprocket')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(8,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(8,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(8,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(8,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="CarrierRollerAVG">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Carrier Roller AVG')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(9,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(9,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(9,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(9,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="CarrierRoller">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef > {{Translate('Carrier Rollers')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(14,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(14,1, row.Components)}}
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(14,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(14,2, row.Components)}}
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="TrackRollerAVG">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef > {{Translate('Track Roller AVG')}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span #actionsPopUp_  class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(10,1, row.Components)}}" (mouseover)="mouseOverTrackRollers($event, row,1)">
                    {{getComponentValue(10,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span #actionsPopUp_ class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(10,2, row.Components)}}" (mouseover)="mouseOverTrackRollers($event, row,2)">
                    {{getComponentValue(10,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="TrackRollerWorst">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Track Roller Worst')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span  class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(11,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(11,1, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(11,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(11,2, row.Components)}}%
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container> <ng-container matColumnDef="TrackRoller" >
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header"    *matHeaderCellDef > {{Translate('Track Rollers')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(13,1, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(13,1, row.Components)}}
                </span>
                <span class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(13,2, row.Components)}}">
                    {{getComponentValue(13,2, row.Components)}}
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="OutstandingActions">
            <mat-header-cell class="eval-header" *matHeaderCellDef> {{Translate('Outstanding Actions')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="no-padding">
                <span #actionsPopUp class="component-span top {{getComponentClass(12,1, row.Components)}}" (mouseover)="mouseOverAction($event, row,1)">
                    {{getOutstandingActions(1, row.Components, row.LastInspection.RecommendedActions)}}
                </span>
                <span #actionsPopUp class="component-span bottom {{getComponentClass(12,2, row.Components)}}"
                    (mouseover)="mouseOverAction($event,row,2)">
                    {{getOutstandingActions(2, row.Components, row.LastInspection.RecommendedActions)}}
                </span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <!--<ng-container matColumnDef="openInNewTab">
            <mat-header-cell class="hover-new-tab__header ignore-click" *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell class="hover-new-tab__cell ignore-click overflow-hidden" *matCellDef="let row">
                <div class="expand-on-hover__element">
                    <button mat-icon-button (click)="openEquipmentNewTab($event, row.Id)" class="ignore-click new-tab-button" matTooltip="Open in new tab">
                        <mat-icon aria-label="Open in new tab" class="ignore-click">open_in_new</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>-->
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="componentDisplayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: componentDisplayedColumns;" class="hand-pointer expand-on-hover" (click)="rowClicked(row)"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [hidden]="equipmentDataLoading" #componentPaginator [pageSize]="loadSize" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
        (page)="componentPageChanged($event)">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: Your link is broken and be specific what you want and what have you tried to achieve the same

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/45rEs/show/    this is the link.

Comment: Your requirement is too wide. You can implement this completely as a new feature. Maybe you should scope it down to make it feasible for yourself. Anyway, the feature is on the way. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13238

Comment: scroll bar is working for mat-table. I need to add a floating scroll bar. Because I have 100 of rows in my table.  scroll all the way to the bottom I can reach the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Could you post at least some code of your implementation? Otherwise, it's hard for the community to help.

Comment: similar to https://stackblitz.com/angular/vrmxygonggx?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts   with more rows and columns

Comment: @wannadream I have update my question with my code.

Comment: Referred to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902850/what-is-the-way-to-add-horizontal-scroll-on-material-ui-table-with-many-columns. It might be the best solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agefve. Another reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdxik6-5cpw2o. Anyway, all of them are not pure or native.

Comment: thanks @wannadream . I will try these solutions. thanks again