# material ui table horizontal scroll

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui, scrollbar

I'm struggling with horizontal scrollbar for my material-ui.
Although I read the documentation and went through some topics here, I can't find how to fix my issue. The horizontal scrollbar never shows up.. Quite annoying

Here is the subset of my code :

**App.js**

```
     <div style={{ height: '100vh', overflow: 'auto', width: '600px' }}>
        <TableHeader headerlabels={headers} datarows={resu} />
     </div >
```

**TableHeader.js**

```
const HeaderTableCell = styled(TableCell)`
&&{
    background-color:#092e68;
    color:white;
    top:0;
    position:sticky;
}
`;

const CustomTableCell = styled(TableCell)`
&&{
    background-color:white;
    color:#092e68;
}
`;


// key, label
const TableHeader = props => {
    const { headerlabels, datarows } = props
    return (
        <Table>
            <TableHead >
                <TableRow key={uuid.v4()} >
                    {headerlabels.map((label) =>
                        (<HeaderTableCell {...props} key={label}>{label}</HeaderTableCell>))}
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody >
                {datarows.map((value, id) =>
                    (
                        <TableRow key={id} >
                            {headerlabels.map((label) =>
                                (<CustomTableCell {...props} key={label}>{value[label]}</CustomTableCell>))}
                        </TableRow>
                    )
                )}
            </TableBody >
        </Table>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 31):

**UPDATE** At the time of my original answer, this was handled as indicated below (wrapping the Table in a Paper with `overflowX: 'auto'`), but the current demo instead handles this by wrapping the `Table` in a `TableContainer` which [handles the `overflowX: 'auto'`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.0/packages/material-ui/src/TableContainer/TableContainer.js#L10).

---

If you look at the code for the [Simple Table](https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/#simple-table) demo, you'll see that it handles this by wrapping the Table in a Paper with `overflowX: 'auto'`.

[image: Edit rm0yx1knxq]

Comment: already tested this before asking the question, but doesn't fix the issue

Comment: On my CodeSandbox I get a horizontal scrollbar. Can you post a CodeSandbox with a version of your code that shows the problem?

Comment: I found the issue. Was nothing to do with my table component, but a styled NavBar on top of the windows put the mess...

Comment: @Jerome can you post a solution, i have a similar problem.

Comment: Hi, difficult to give you the solution, as the issue was in formatting a DIV with width and height wrong values. This div was in a parent page and not in the table code. I would suggest you remove all your styling, except in the table component, that shoud work

Comment: Refer this answer, I use mui-v4 and this did the trick for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52746582/9498804

Answer (score 0):

For me just wrapping my `<Table>` with `<TableContainer>` (without any attributes) worked fine